# PyTorch: Compute Hessian matrix of the model

Tags: python, pytorch, regression, standard-error, hessian-matrix

Say that, for some reason, I want to fit a linear regression using PyTorch, as illustrated below.

How could I compute the **Hessian matrix** of the model to, ultimately, compute the standard error for my parameter estimates?

```
import torch 
import torch.nn as nn
# set seed 
torch.manual_seed(42)
# define the model
class OLS_pytorch(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, X, Y):
        super(OLS_pytorch, self).__init__()
        self.X = X
        self.Y = Y
        self.beta = nn.Parameter(torch.ones(X.shape[1], 1, requires_grad=True))
        self.intercept = nn.Parameter(torch.ones(1, requires_grad=True))
        self.loss = nn.MSELoss()
        
    def forward(self):
        return self.X @ self.beta + self.intercept
    
    def fit(self, lr=0.01, epochs=1000):
        optimizer = torch.optim.Adam(self.parameters(), lr=lr)
        for epoch in range(epochs):
            optimizer.zero_grad()
            loss = self.loss(self.forward(), self.Y)
            loss.backward()
            optimizer.step()
            if epoch % 10 == 0:
                print(f"Epoch {epoch} loss: {loss.item()}")
        return self
```

Generating some data and using the model

```
# Generate some data    
X = torch.randn(100, 1)
Y = 2 * X + 3 + torch.randn(100, 1)
# fit the model
model = OLS_pytorch(X, Y)
model.fit()
#extract parameters 
model.beta, model.intercept

#Epoch 980 loss: 0.7803605794906616
#Epoch 990 loss: 0.7803605794906616
#(Parameter containing:
# tensor([[2.0118]], requires_grad=True),
# Parameter containing:
# tensor([3.0357], requires_grad=True))
```

---

For instance, in R, using the same data and the `lm()` function, I recover the same parameters, but I am also able to recover the Hessian matrix, and them I am able to compute standard errors.

```
ols <- lm(Y ~ X, data = xy)
ols$coefficients
#(Intercept)           X 
#   3.035674    2.011811 
vcov(ols)
#              (Intercept)             X
# (Intercept)  0.0079923921 -0.0004940884
# X           -0.0004940884  0.0082671053

summary(ols)
# Coefficients:
#             Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
# (Intercept)  3.03567    0.08940   33.96   <2e-16 ***
# X            2.01181    0.09092   22.13   <2e-16 ***
# ---
# Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
```

---

**UPDATE**: Using the answer from [@cherrywoods](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75221312/10714156)

here is how you would match the standard errors produced by `lm()` in R

```
# predict   
y_pred = model.X @ model.beta + model.intercept
sigma_hat = torch.sum((y_pred - model.Y)**2)/ (N-2) #2 is the number of estimated parameters. 

from torch.autograd.functional import hessian
def loss(beta, intercept):
    y_pred = model.X @ beta + intercept
    return model.loss(y_pred, model.Y)


H = torch.Tensor(hessian(loss, (model.beta, model.intercept)))
vcov = torch.sqrt(torch.diag(sigma_hat*torch.inverse(H/2)) )
print(vcov)
#tensor([0.9092, 0.8940], grad_fn=<SqrtBackward0>)
```

Comment: Just in case someone else is looking at this question later for seeing how to train a linear regression model in PyTorch: There is actually a faster way using the normal equation: https://eli.thegreenplace.net/2014/derivation-of-the-normal-equation-for-linear-regression/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can compute the Hessian using [torch.autograd.functional.hessian](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.autograd.functional.hessian.html).

```py
from torch.autograd.functional import hessian

def loss(beta, intercept):
    y_pred = model.X @ beta + intercept
    return model.loss(y_pred, model.Y)

H = hessian(loss, (model.beta, model.intercept))
```

Comment: Thank you, @cherrywoods. However, could you elaborate more using the example provided?

Comment: Actually, I don't think I understand what you are trying to do. In fact, the Hessian (matrix of second derivatives) of the linear model will be all 0 always. Are we talking about the same Hessian?

Comment: I am talking about the Hessian matrix that you can then use to compute standard errors of the estimated parameters, as in [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2864585/hessian-on-linear-least-squares-problem)

Comment: Ok, so Hessian of the MSE loss with respect to `beta` and `intercept`? I will update my answer.

Comment: Exactly. I am searching for the Hessian of the MSE loss evaluated at the optimum found by the algorithm. Which, in this case, are `beta` and `intercept`, indeed. I am sorry for the ambiguity.

Comment: No problem, I though you wanted to derive the regression output with respect to the input or the parameters.

Comment: I edited my question using your solution to match standard errors produced by the R function `lm()`.  Extra details [here](https://max.pm/posts/hessian_ls/).